# Heroku rejecting my app all of a sudden (env: bundle: No such file or directory)

Tags: heroku, deployment

I tried deploying my application today and my deployments are for the first time being rejected.

My deployment output is below. I've tried the following with no change in outcome:

- Deploying with no Ruby version in Gemfile
- Deploying with 2.1.0 in Gemfile
- Deploying using a custom BUILDPACK_URL at https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git
- Deploying from a different branch
- Deploying from a teammate's machine
- Rolling back to last successfully deployed commit, changing a line in the README, committed and redeployed.

I had successfully deployed just last night. I only have made HTML and CSS changes to the new code I want to commit, so nothing in the app settings has been changed since the last successful deployment.

Why would Heroku be now rejecting my app deployments?

Thanks!

```
Fetching repository, done.
Counting objects: 11, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 496 bytes, done.
Total 6 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.5.2
Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs    vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
env: bundle: No such file or directory
Bundler Output: env: bundle: No such file or directory
!
! Failed to install gems via Bundler.
!
! Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
To git@heroku.com:myapp.git
! [remote rejected] development -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:myapp.git'
```

Answer (score 0):

Heroku dropped support for Rails 1.9 and that was in the PATH.  I had some trouble dropping the PATH because heroku had some hack where it was configured, but would not drop (probably because it was a default).

So I ended up setting the PATH to something

```
heroku config:set PATH=blah
```

and then unsetting it.

```
heroku config:remove PATH
```

That seems to have stuck.